# How to redirect url using tuckey urlrewrite

Tags: java, url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I have a webpage named 'index.html', and I can use 'http://example.com/index.html' to access it.

What I intend to do is to access the 'index.html' using 'http://example.com/index.htm'; If using 'http://example.com/index.html', an 404 will return.

I'm using `tuckey urlrewrite`, and here is my config xml:

```
<rule>
    <from>^/(.*).htm$</from>
    <to>/$1.html</to>
</rule>

<outbound-rule>
    <from>^/(.*).html$</from>
    <to >/$1.htm</to>
</outbound-rule>
```

After deploying it, I can use 'http://example.com/index.htm' to access my index.html, **but when I'm using 'http://example.com/index.html', it still can access my index.html.**

What should I do to make the server returning 404 when *.html is being requested? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `<set type="status">404</set>` for a rule maching `/.*.html$` ?